# Adapting Latex class and template file to an Rmarkdown template

Tags: rmarkdown, bookdown

I'm trying to adapt an unofficial University of South Florida Latex document class and template file which are available from [http://shell.cas.usf.edu/~saito/grad/](http://shell.cas.usf.edu/%7Esaito/grad/) into an [Rmarkdown template](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudio-extensions/rmarkdown_templates.html) similar to the [thesisdown](https://github.com/ismayc/thesisdown) and [huskydown](https://github.com/benmarwick/huskydown) packages. After playing with that for a while I was able to get a package that has a custom template (https://github.com/ailich/bulldown) and can be installed with `remotes::install_github("ailich/bulldown")`. The document will knit, but if I add any headers to the child documents (e.g. # Chapter 1) I get the error "! Undefined control sequence. l.49 \hypertarget". [I've included a text file](https://github.com/ailich/bulldown/blob/master/Creating%20R%20Markdown%20Template%20for%20USF%20Dissertation.txt) which lists the steps I took to create this R package/template and the edits I had to make to various files. Does anyone know how to fix this issue or why it would occur? I'm not very familiar with Latex so I've had trouble debugging this.

Comment: this appears to be more of an R question than a latex one but hypertarget is defined by the hyperref package so make sure you generated code includes that

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll try asking on stack overflow as there might be some more people on the R side of things there. The hypertargets seem to be related to the conversion of the Rmarkdown document to Latex by Pandoc as there's no hypertargets in the original template.tex file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished with `"-r", "markdown-auto_identifiers"`

It can be specified in the YAML with

```
output: 
  bulldown::thesis_pdf:
    pandoc_args: [
      "-r", "markdown-auto_identifiers"
      ]
```

or in a function like `bookdown::pdf_book` using the `pandoc_args` argument

`pandoc_args = c(pandoc_args, "--top-level-division=chapter", "-r","markdown-auto_identifiers")`